# SharpSvn: Getting repository structure and individual files

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I am trying to build a simple repository browser into a web application and have been looking into using SharpSvn to help.

I can find all the usual physical commands, like update, commit, that would actually make changes to the repository or a working copy but am struggling to find a way to query a repositories structure or contents.

Is there any way I can read the structure of the repository so I can display a simple explorer like interface in a web page (i.e. tree view of directories plus a list of files)?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061016/sharpsvn-read-all-filenames

Comment: thanks that's exactly the kind of start I was after

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `SharpSvn.SvnClient` class has a [GetList()](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnClient_GetList_1.htm) function that works really well:

```
using (SvnClient svnClient = new SvnClient())
{
   Collection<SvnListEventArgs> contents;
   List<string> files = new List<string>();
   if (svnClient.GetList(new Uri(svnUrl), out contents))
   {
      foreach(SvnListEventArgs item in contents)
      {
         files.Add(item.Path);
      }
   }
}
```

Once you have the collection, you can get the path of each item at the location.  You can also use the Entry object to get information concerning each item, including whether it is a directory or a file, when it was last modified, etc.