# SharpSVN: Getting Entire Repository Structure

Tags: sharpsvn

I looked at the following post ([SharpSVN: Getting Repository Structure and Individual Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883196/sharpsvn-getting-repository-structure-and-individual-files)) and can successfully get the structure of my repository only at the main level. What I need to do is get the ENTIRE structure for every folder/subfolder under the main level. This is the code I have so far:

```
 Dim svnUrl As String = "https:\\SVN MAIN LEVEL REPOSITORY"
    Using svnClient As New SvnClient()
        Dim contents As Collection(Of SvnListEventArgs)
        Dim files As New List(Of String)()
        If svnClient.GetList(New Uri(svnUrl), contents) Then
            For Each item As SvnListEventArgs In contents
                'files.Add(item.Path)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Path)
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(item.Path)
            Next
        End If
    End Using
```

What am I missing or do I need to recursively call the function and pass in the levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own recursive sub due to the specific requirements I had:

```
 If svnClient.GetList(New Uri(svnUrl), contents) Then
            ReDim Preserve node_array(UBound(node_array) + 1)
            node_array(UBound(node_array)) = LibraryNode.Text
            For Each SubFolder As SvnListEventArgs In contents
                Dim MainNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(SubFolder.Name)
                If SubFolder.Name <> "My Top Level Folder" Then
                    ReDim Preserve node_array(UBound(node_array) + 1)
                    node_array(UBound(node_array)) = LibraryNode.Text & "\" & MainNode.Text

                    Dim thelevel As String = LibraryNode.Text & "\" & MainNode.Text
                    LibraryNode.Nodes.Add(MainNode)
                    currentlevel = 0
                    FillTreeViewNodesSVN(SubFolder.Uri.ToString, MainNode, svnClient, thelevel, currentlevel)
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

The above calls the recursion sub:

```
  Public Sub FillTreeViewNodesSVN(ByVal SubFolder As String, ByVal MainNode As TreeNode, ByVal svnClient As SvnClient, ByVal thelevel As String, ByVal currentlevel As Integer)

    Dim contents As Collection(Of SvnListEventArgs)
    Dim files As New List(Of String)()
    If svnClient.GetList(New Uri(SubFolder), contents) Then
        For Each item As SvnListEventArgs In contents
            If item.Uri.ToString <> SubFolder And InStr(item.Uri.ToString, "tag") > 0 Then
                Dim SubNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(item.Name)
                ReDim Preserve node_array(UBound(node_array) + 1)
                node_array(UBound(node_array)) = thelevel & "\" & SubNode.Text

                thelevel = thelevel & "\" & SubNode.Text
                currentlevel = currentlevel + 1
                If currentlevel < 2 Then
                    FillTreeViewNodesSVN(item.Uri.ToString, SubNode, svnClient, thelevel, currentlevel)
                End If
                currentlevel = currentlevel - 1
                thelevel = thelevel.Replace("\" & SubNode.Text, "")
            End If
        Next
    End If


End Sub
```

Combined the 2 create a node list of the folders 2 levels deep of ONLY the TAGS folder. This gets me all of the deployed TAGs for a given project.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass SvnDepth.Infinite on the Depth property of the optional args object that you can pass to .GetList.

But be careful with calling this function on the root of a really huge repository as everything is cached in ram before you would see the first results.

Using .List() with a callback function reports results while they arrive, allowing the GC to release items as soon as you are done.